# What is the difference between principal component analysis and singular value decomposition in image processing?

Tags: computer-vision, comparison, image-processing, principal-component-analysis, singular-value-decomposition

What is the difference between principal component analysis and singular value decomposition in image processing? Which one performs better, and why?

Comment: Is there are particular (image processing) application you're interested in? PCA and SVD are quite general techniques.

Comment: The application are Missing Person Detection using python @nbro